# Python Calling Child's Method from Parent Class

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I'm working with [yapsy](http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/) to setup some runtime plugins for a project. I've derived my own Plugin type from the IPlugin abstract class:

```
class MyPlugin(IPlugin):
    def __init__(self):
        # call IPlugin's constructor, to initialize is_activated, activate()
        # and deactivate().
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.__is_installed = self.installed

    @property
    def installed():
        # this must be implemented in the plugin
        raise NotImplementedError("installed must be implemented by %s" % self)
```

And the plugin looks like this:

```
from mypackage.plugin import MyPlugin

class TestPlugin(MyPlugin):
    @property
    def installed():
        return False
```

The call to self.installed calls the `installed` method from `MyPlugin` and not the overridden `installed` method from `TestPlugin`. I've been looking through all kinds of documentation on python inheritance and super(), but I'm not seeing (or understanding) what I need. Any suggestions?

Edit: I wrote up a quick example to confirm that things work the way I though they did. The child method should be called "automatically" instead of the parent's method. Since it's not, I assume it must be something that yapsy is doing. Still trying to figure it out.

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'parent'
        print('%s\t\t Parent.__init__()' % self.name)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'child'

        # super doesn't overriding name
        print('%s\t\t Child.__init__()\t before super()' % self.name)
        super(Parent, self).__init__()
        print('%s\t\t Child.__init__()\t after super()' % self.name)

        # this does override name
        print('%s\t\t Child.__init__()\t before Parent.__init__()' % self.name)
        Parent.__init__(self)
        print('%s\t\t Child.__init__()\t after Parent.__init__()' % self.name)

        self.set_name()

    def set_name(self):
        print('%s\t\t Child.__init__()\t before Child.set_name()' % self.name)
        self.name = 'child'
        print('%s\t\t Child.__init__()\t after Child.set_name()' % self.name)


class Grandchild(Child):
    # when creating an instance of grandchild, this method is called and
    # Parent.set_name is not.
    def set_name(self):
        print('%s\t\t Grandchild.__init__()\t before Grandchild.set_name()' % self.name)
        self.name = 'grandchild'
        print('%s\t Grandchild.__init__()\t after Grandchild.set_name()' % self.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Parent()
    c = Child()
    g = Grandchil
```

Comment: `super(self.__class__, self).__init__()` should be `super(MyPlugin, self).__init__()`, otherwise you'll end up with an infinite recursion. After fixing this your code works fine for me.

Comment: Read: [If you see `super(type(self), self)`, the code is doing it wrong. It is a bug. It is super-wrong.](http://pyrandom.blogspot.in/2013/04/super-wrong.html)

Comment: This is interesting. I'm confused though. The way it's written right now - IPlugin__init__() is called and it sets the is_activated attribute appropriately. However, if I change this to `super(IPlugin, self).__init__()`, the attribute is not set.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this and my solution was this

Base plugin class

```
class PluginBase():

        def generate(self):
             print('PluginBase plugin(generate)')

        def generated_files(self):
            print('PluginBase plugin(generated files)')
            return {}
```

Actual plugin

```
from PluginBase import PluginBase
from yapsy.IPlugin import IPlugin

class Test(PluginBase, IPlugin):

    def generate(self):
         print('Test plugin(generate)')

    def generated_files(self):
        print('Test plugin(generated files)')
        return {'file1': 'some/path/to/file1',
                'file2': 'some/other/path/to/file2'}
```

So inherit IPlugin directly in your actual plugin class rather than the ancestor class